# How to send an object in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I was trying to make a post request to the api route I just created.

[image]

In the backend I have something like this

```
console.log(typeof req.body)
console.log(req.body)
const { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber } = req.body
console.log(`Variable Values`, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber)
```

Here I am getting typeof as `String` and body as this

```
{
        firstName: "Varun",
        lastName: "Bindal",
        email: "iva@gmail.com",
        phoneNumber: "+91-8888"
}
```

What I want is that the typeof to be object so I can de-structure it, How can I make a request from postman in this case (I don't want use JSON.parse)

Comment: You will have to parse it somehow. Parsing javascript object syntax is fairly complicated if you want to support all possible features (expressions, computed property, comments etc.) which is why the JSON format was designed specifically simple that it is still compatible with javascript object syntax but also easier to implement a parser for

Comment: HTTP will **only** ever send strings to the backend (even JPEGS are simply binary strings) - if you don't want to use JSON you need to implement a parser manually. In the old days before `JSON.parse` was implemented a simple cheat is to just `eval` the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type of body from raw text to JSON (application/json) by clicking on the text button right next to your GraphQL option.

Comment: He is not sending JSON though - either he needs to send it as text or change his payload to valid JSON syntax

Answer (score 2):

[image: see image]

Click  the "Text" beside it will show you a dropdown. Just choose "JSON" instead of "Text"

Comment: Note that he's not sending JSON - he will also need to change his payload to valid JSON syntax if he changes the dropdown to JSON

Answer (score 2):

Choose the JSON option as shown in the picture.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9csY.png]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use `JSON.parse`?

It's important to know that JSON and a javascript object are two different things.

JSON is a *data format* format that can be used in various environments while a javascript object is a data structure/concept in javascript.

When making a HTTP request you can send data via a few different methods. A few prominent ones being XML, Binary and JSON (They all will be represented as text, even binary).

Since you're building a API with javascript I would recommended that you use JSON in your requests and responses. JSON has also somewhat become the "standard" for APIs these days. It's also very easy to parse JSON to javascript objects and the other way around.

Please note that you maybe also need to tell postman to set the [Content Type Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `application/json`. You also would need to change your body to be actual valid JSON:

```
{
  "firstName": "Varun",
  "lastName": "Bindal",
  "email": "iva@gmail.com",
  "phoneNumber": "+91-8888"
}
```

I can recommend that you read the following article explaining what JSON is and how you use it: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your object body is of type text. Change it to JSON using the little dropdown and the POST request will work.

Cheers!

Comment: But he's not sending JSON. He wants to send an object literal (note that his syntax is invalid JSON but valid object literal)

Comment: His JSON syntax is also wrong, as i have noticed. He has to change that. But from his question, all he needs is  a JSON object . "...What I want is that the typeof to be object so I can de-structure it, How can I make a request from postman in this case..."